# Change object type with hydrators, inside a pagination collection with ZendFramework 2 + Doctrine 2

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, pagination, zend-framework2

I'm building a RESTful API, and I have problem.

**The goal:**
I want to hydrate a collection, that comes from a Paginator.
I mean, inside the collection, I don't want to return a Project object, I want to return a [HalCollection](https://github.com/phly/PhlyRestfully/blob/master/src/PhlyRestfully/HalCollection.php) of HalResources. To create these HalResources, I need to use the Project object (plus additional information).

**The scenario:**
I create a class ProjectHydrator, that implements [HydratorInterface](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/modules/zend.stdlib.hydrator.html), with the two methods:

```
class ProjectHydrator implements HydratorInterface  {
public function hydrate(array $data, $project){ .... }
public function extract($project) { .... }
}
```

I attach this Hydrator to my module, inside the module.config.php

```
'phlyrestfully' => array (
'renderer' => array (
    'hydrators' => array (
        'MYPROJECT\Entity\Project' => new \MYPROJECT\Hydrators\ProjectHydrator()
        )
    ),
    ......
)
```

And the fetchAll of the listener method y create the pagination in this way:

```
$dql = 'SELECT e FROM \MYPROJECT\Entity\Project e';
$query = $this->getEntityManager()->createQuery($dql);  //  Class: \Doctrine\ORM\Query
$ormPaginator       = new \Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Pagination\Paginator($query);                         //Class: Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Pagination\Paginator
$doctrinePaginator  = new \DoctrineORMModule\Paginator\Adapter\DoctrinePaginator($ormPaginator);    //Class: DoctrineORMModule\Paginator\Adapter\DoctrinePaginator
$paginator          = new \Zend\Paginator\Paginator($doctrinePaginator);                            //Class: Zend\Paginator\Paginator
return $paginator;
```

**The problem:** The hydrator is being executed... but is called the method "extract", with parameter a Project object. In this method I must return and array, and this is my problem, I want to return a HalResource, not an array.

I want to use the hydrator to change the type of object, from Project object (project Entity object) to a HalResource. To build this HalResource, I want to use the Project object plus an array with other parameters.

What I am doing wrong?
Any ideas?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Other ZF2 / Doctrine2 components can't iterate through your HalResource. You should return array or Iterator / ArrayAccess instance.

Comment: Hi! Thank you very much for your help.
I found another way, that is extending the "Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Pagination\Paginator", creating a customized Paginator. In this paginator, we overwrite the method  "public function getIterator(){}", to allow passing as parameter to the method "getResult()" the hydrator that we want.

Answer (score 5):

No need to extend the `Doctrine Paginator`, simply set your query hydration mode to hydrate array mode.

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Query;
use Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Pagination\Paginator as DoctrinePaginator;
use DoctrineORMModule\Paginator\Adapter\DoctrinePaginator as PaginatorAdapter;
use Zend\Paginator\Paginator;

$dql = 'SELECT e FROM \MYPROJECT\Entity\Project e';
$query = $this->getEntityManager()->createQuery($dql);

//Set query hydration mode
$query->setHydrationMode(Query::HYDRATE_ARRAY);

$paginator = new Paginator(new PaginatorAdapter(new DoctrinePaginator($query)));

return $paginator;
```

Hope it helps.